# Canvas event works only once

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter, event-handling

I'm writing a program that processes some data and shows the result as a plot. I attached the plot to a canvas so that it can be shown in the same Tkinter window instead of being displayed in a new one. I want the figure to be displayed in a separate window when the user clicks it, using `mpl_connect`. However, it works only once. If I click the canvas for the second time nothing happens. I've also tried to make a button and bind an event to it, but the same problem happens: it works only once.

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I'm making and how to fix it?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *

class mclass:
    def __init__(self,  window):
        self.window = window
        self.leftframe= Frame (self.window)
        self.rightframe= Frame (self.window)
        self.leftframe.pack (side= LEFT, anchor=N)
        self.rightframe.pack (side=RIGHT, anchor=N)

        self.box = Entry(self.leftframe)
        self.button = Button (self.leftframe, text="check", command=self.plot)
        self.plotlabel= Label (self.leftframe, text="The following is the plot")
        self.box.grid (row=1, column=1)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column= 1)
        self.plotlabel.grid (row=3, column=1)

    def plot (self):
        x=np.array ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        v= np.array ([16,16.31925,17.6394,16.003,17.2861,17.3131,19.1259,18.9694,22.0003,22.81226])
        p= np.array ([16.23697,     17.31653,     17.22094,     17.68631,     17.73641 ,    18.6368,
            19.32125,     19.31756 ,    21.20247  ,   22.41444   ,  22.11718  ,   22.12453])

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
        a = fig.add_subplot(111)
        a.scatter(v,x,color='red')
        a.plot(p, range(2 +max(x)),color='blue')
        a.invert_yaxis()

        a.set_title ("Estimation Grid", fontsize=16)
        a.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        a.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.rightframe)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column= 2)
        canvas.draw()
        cid= fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: plt.show())

window= Tk()
start= mclass (window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Suspect you are running into issues with the global state inherent in `pyplot`. I would avoid using `pyplot` + embedding at almost all costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tcaswell noted, when embedding, you can't use `plt.figure` or `plt.show`.

The reason you're only getting a single click to work is that you're calling `plt.show()` in your "on-click" callback.  `plt.show()` will try to start *another* Tk mainloop inside your application's mainloop, locking things up in the process.

Also, you're creating two `canvas`es and attaching them to the same figure.

`plt.figure()` creates a figure, a canvas, and a figure manager, then registers them with the global `pyplot` state.  You only want one of those things to happen, so you should call `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(...)` instead. (or `Figure` in your case, as that's how you've imported it)

---

The good news is that this is a two-line fix.  Change `plt.figure(...)` to `Figure(...)` and don't call `plt.show()` in your on-click event.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe, what can I call instead of plt.show?

Comment: `plt.show()` is equivalent to your `window.mainloop()`.  It's not something that makes sense to call inside of a button press callback. What do you want the callback to do?

Comment: Thanks, the canvas already shows in the main window of the application, when clicked I want it to be showed in a separate window like the plt.show shows the figure in a separate window that can be maximized and minimized by the user. How can I do this? Thanks.